# How to create a singleton service in asp.net core in which Iconfiguration is being passed into its constructor

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create a service class for my constructor in which I need to load a lot of configurations from my appsettings.json.
I want this service to be created as singleton and need to load configurations values in the service itself. So please anyone suggest me the best way to do so. I am creating asp.net core webapi and using its core DI built in container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration is already pre-registered by the host that is used with ASP.NET Core. So you can just register your service as you would any other singleton service, and have it depend on the configuration by requiring `IConfiguration` in the constructor:

```cs
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public MyService(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
}
```

You can then register this service as a singleton directly in your `ConfigureService` method:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
```

Things that now depend on your service, for example constructors, will automatically get a reference to that service instance. And since it is registered as singleton, it will only be created once by the DI container.

If you want a bit more control over your configuration, then I would suggest you to adapt the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to make sure that you can work with strongly typed configuration and to avoid unrelated configuration value from spilling into services that shouldn’t not have access to them.